# Breaking down array values and assign to variables

Tags: php

I have an array as shown here

```
25|12|3|53
```

I want to break and store the values in the array on to variables as shown below.

```
$variable1 = 25
$variable2 = 12
...
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Do you know how many array elements you might have? is it just 4 items exactly every time?

Answer (score 4):

Certainly that is possible:

```
<?php
$input = [25,12,3,53];
foreach ($input as $key => $val) {
  $varname = 'var' . ($key+1);
  $$varname = $val;
}
var_dump([$var1, $var2, $var3, $var4]);
```

The output obviously is:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(25)
  [1]=>
  int(12)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(53)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To do exactly as you asked:

```
$array = array(25, 'another', 'yet another', 'value');
foreach($array as $index => $value)
{
     ${'variable' . ++$index} = $value;
}

echo $variable1; //shows 25
```

Comment: This is not exactly clean style: you manually increment the index variable used in your loop... what does that mean for subsequent variable names?

Comment: Yes it is clean. The index is not used by anything else and he wanted it to be starting at 1. Although you actually have a point if it were used.

Comment: That is not what I referred to. The issue is that you manually increment the iteration index each time only to again overwrite it for the next iteration. That is hard to read, thus unclean style. Instead of `++$index` this definitely should be `$index+1` here, _especially_ since that variable is not used anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bracket `{ }` to create new variable from variable

```
foreach ($array as $i => $arr)
{
  ${'variable'.$i+1} = $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the elements of an array into variables only makes sense, if you have a specific number of elements, so you can work with that distinct set of variables in your code. In all other cases you should go on to work with arrays instead.

Because of that, this answer assumes, that your array has a distinct set of elements. In that case you can use [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to transform the elements into variables:

```
$array = [12, 25, 3, 53];

list($value1, $value2, $value3, $value4) = $array;

echo $value1; // echoes 12
echo $value2; // echoes 25
echo $value3; // echoes 3
echo $value4; // echoes 53
```

With PHP 7.1 and higher the following short code can be used aswell:

```
$array = [12, 25, 3, 53];

[$value1, $value2, $value3, $value4] = $array;

echo $value1; // echoes 12
echo $value2; // echoes 25
echo $value3; // echoes 3
echo $value4; // echoes 53
```